# Request data from REST API in JSON format in C++

Tags: c++, json, rest

I have one application were I need to request data from REST API in Json format and send Json Data to Cloud using REST API in C++. I googled but I find very few resources

As I am new to C++ coding

From where should I start ,
How to use dummy database to call the JSon message through Rest API

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what is usage of dummy database?

Comment: As I am new and I dont have anything, How should i start for the above application

Comment: @Piu I add one answer

Answer (score 0):

ITNOA

If you want to call web API in C++ project you can use [cpprestsdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk)1

but [cpprestsdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk) does not actively development and maintain only, so if you want another active library for using to achieve communication web service with `http` and `json` you can use  [Boost.Beast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/beast/doc/html/index.html) as `http` client and use [JSON for Modern C++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) as `json` serializer/de-serializer library

*1. The C++ REST SDK is a Microsoft project for cloud-based client-server communication in native code using a modern asynchronous C++ API design. This project aims to help C++ developers connect to and interact with services.*

Comment: I find cpprestsdk useful but it is mentioned not to use as it is not active , I am not able to get with Boostbeat easily , any other suggestion